Centripetal force derivation in 1950's textbooks
The caption to this image from Arthur Stinner's article states that

This conceptualization of centripetal acceleration in terms of free
fall around the earth was still used in textbooks in the 1950s.

I was wondering if I could find a physics textbook from 1950's (or older) that has a similar derivation?
I did reverse image search and I found similar images but they were more recent than 1950's. I found one textbook from 1950's but that did not have any diagrams like this.


Have you searched the Internet Archiv? They have all the old textbooks online. Search Physics Textbooks from that era.

No, but now I did. I found a few textbooks but they all use standard vector method found in modern textbooks.

I checked your original book chapter that was linked. He does not discuss this Figure 9 in detail. If the author is alive, it may be worth contacting him.

@ACR Thanks. The author died in 2014 but he asked that his website be kept alive. He had a similar paper http://www.arthurstinner.com/stinner/pdfs/1994-storyofforce.pdf where he used the same figure. The caption attributes this method of deriving $v^2/r$ to Newton. I think this is Prop.4 in Book 1 in Newton's Principia. Since Prop.4 doesn't have a diagram this must have been developed in a later date by textbook writers.
